# connecting shiny app to mysql database on server

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

can anyone help on how t connect a shiny with mysql database on server. 
I can do the connection locally on my system but how can we do the same on server to make it available online

Comment: Have a look at the `dplyr`- and the `RMySQL`-Package

Comment: I am trying with RMySQL package, but thr is some problem with the installation.Can you suggest something, I am using it wor windows based Rstudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install below package from R console

> install.packages("RMySQL", dependencies = TRUE)

And you can cennect mysql database as below:

Code inside **server.R**:

```
library(RMySQL)

options(mysql = list(
 "host" = "127.0.0.1",
 "port" = 3306,
 "user" = "myuser",
 "password" = "mypassword"
))

databaseName <- "DATABASE NAME"
table <- "TABLE"
```

Hope it will help you to connect your application with mysql database. If you still need help let me know :)